# javascript if/else program not producing alert as expected

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to write a simple program that does the following:

Build a function declaration named changePowerTotal that takes in:

The total current power generated (a number)
A generator ID (a number)
The new status of a generator (a string that says “on” or “off”)
And the amount of power produced by that generator (a number)
Your function should:

return the new total of generated power
alert the technician in the following formats
For switching on:

Generator #2 is now on, adding 62 MW, for a total of 62 MW!
Or for switching off:

Generator #2 is now off, removing 62 MW, for a total of 0 MW!

My solution so far is as follows:

```
var generatorId = 2;
var status = "off";
var totalCurrentPower = 62;
var powerProduced = 62;

function changePowerTotal (totalCurrentPower, generatorId, status, powerProduced){
    if(status = "off"){
        var offPowerTotal = totalCurrentPower - powerProduced;
        alert('Generator #' + generatorId + ' is now ' + status + ' , removing ' + powerProduced + 'mw, for a total of ' + newPowerTotal + 'MW!');
        return offPowerTotal;
    }
    else {
        var onPowerTotal = totalCurrentPower + powerProduced;
        alert('Generator #' + generatorId + ' is now ' + status + ' , adding ' + powerProduced + 'mw, for a total of ' + newPowerTotal + 'MW!');
        return onPowerTotal;
    }
}
```

The trouble is that this is not throwing an alert, and even worse for me a newbie, its not producing an error in the javascript console. What am I doing wrong?

If I break it down and just assign all variables in alert as global and then do an alert, it works (see below). This makes me believe it has something to do with the if/else within my function.

> var generatorId = 2; var status = "off"; var totalCurrentPower = 62;
>   var powerProduced = 62; newPowerTotal = 0;
>
> alert('Generator #' + generatorId + ' is now ' + status + ' , removing
>   ' + powerProduced + 'mw, for a total of ' + newPowerTotal + 'MW!');

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've also tried removing the returns and just leaving the alerts. That didn't seem to help.

Comment: `===` is better to use than `==` as it checks type also. `===` basically means exactly equal to.

Comment: You are assigning `offPowerTotal` but then on the next line using `newPowerTotal`.

Comment: do you really want to check a boolean condition in `if else`? Because your `if` condition will always be true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the problems already mentioned, I think maybe the problem is that you aren't calling the function. You need to have

```
changePowerTotal()
```

Called somewhere for it to work, or even throw an error. Also, make sure all your variables are defined, and remember "=" is assignment, to check a variable use "==" or "===".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the statements above, [here is a plunker example of it implemented](http://embed.plnkr.co/I3o3ye/preview) hope this helps.